# A serializable schedule but not conflict serializable

Tags: database, transactions, conflict, schedule

I need to an example of schedule that was serializable schedule but it wasn't conflict serializable

Comment: Is my answer what you want or not?

Answer (score 0):

Consider an example as following, operations are listed in chronological order:

T1: Read A
T2: Write A
T3: Read A
T1: Write A
T3: Write A

You can verify that the schedule above is conflict serializable but not view serializable. You may also check this [page](https://www.gatevidyalay.com/tag/conflict-and-view-serializability-in-dbms/) for more detailed explaination.

Answer (score -1):

Any view serializable schedule that is not conflict serializable must contain a blind write.

Blind write means A transaction writes the database, without reading the database variable.

That means, if we know the database variable name. If we write using that variable with some values.

The transaction is like the below, that is blind writes.

Example:-

```
Transaction T1                           Transaction T2

  Write(X)
                                            Write(X)
  Write(Y)
                                            Write(Y)
```

In the above example, we didn't read the variable X, but we are writing the X.

If we write the database without using the old value, There is no conflict serializability. In here we have to replace the old value in the database. The blind writes is done in two transactions with using the same database variable name.That time also it is a serializable.

Comment: "If we write the database without using the old value, There is no conflict serializability" : This statement is false. It is not necessary that a schedule with a blind write will always be non conflict serializable.